# Machine learning method which is able to integrate prior knowledge in a decision tree

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, decision-tree

Does any of you know a machine learning method or combination of methods which makes it possible to integrate prior knowledge in the building process of a decision tree?

With "prior knowledge" I mean the information if a feature in a particular node is really responsible for the resulting classification or not. Imagine we only have a short period of time where our features are measured and in this period of time we have a correlation between features. If we now would measure the same features again, we probably would **not** get a correlation between those features, because it was just a coincidence that they are correlated. Unfortunately it is not possible to measure again.

The problem which arises with that is: the feature which is chosen by the algorithms to perform a split is not the feature which actually leads to the split in the real world. In other words the strongly correlated feature is chosen by the algorithm while the other feature is the one which should be chosen. That's why I want to set rules / causalities / constraints for the tree learning process.

Answer (score 1):

"a particular feature in an already learned tree" - the typical decision tree has one feature per node, and therefore each feature can appear in many different nodes. Similarly, each leaf has one classification, but each classification may appear in multiple leafs. (And with a binary classifier, any non-trivial tree must have repeated classifications).

This means that you can enumerate all leafs and sort them by classification to get uniform subsets of leaves. For each such subset, you can analyze all paths from the root of the tree to see which features occurred. But this will be a large set.

"But in my case there are some features which are strongly correlated ... The feature which is choosen by the algorithms to perform a split is not the feature which actually leads to the split in the real world."
It's been said that every model is wrong, but some models are useful. If the features are indeed strongly correlated, choosing this "wrong" feature doesn't really affect the model.

You can of course just modify the split algorithm in tree building. Trivially, "if the remaining classes are A and B, use split S, else determine the split using algorithm C4.5" is a valid splitting algorithm that hardcodes pre-existing knowledge about two specific classes without being restricted to just that case.

But note that it might just be easier to introduce a combined class `A+B` in the decision tree, and then decide between A and B in postprocessing.

Comment: In my case choosing the wrong feature does affect the model, because I want to use the decision tree to visualize causalities within the data and the features are correlated randomly... What do you exactly mean by "introduce a combined class"? Do you have a specific program in mind where this is possible? Thanks

Comment: @JanLob: If you want to visualize causalities, C4.5 won't give you that. In fact, no data-oriented method can give you that. They work on correlation, not causation. I don't understand how you say here that features are "correlated randomly" when the question says the exact opposite "strongly correlated". I suspect you need to define your problem a lot better; chances are that you don't see the answer because you don't have the real question yet.

Comment: @ MSalters: Sorry for the bad formulation! I didn't mean features are correlated randomly, but random features are correlated. This means, we only have a short period of time where our features were measured and in this period of time we have a correlation between features. But if we would measure the same features again, we probably wouldn't get a correlation between those features, because it was just a coincidence that they are correlated. That's why I want to set some rules by hand (the prior knowledge).

Comment: Well, technically nothing is stopping you from hardcoding an initial tree, and then let C4.5 run from there on. The algorithm is pretty stateless, it performs node splits without taking the nodes parents into account.